# Two matrices identical after row and column swaps. Is there a standard form for them?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have two matrices A and B. They are the same matrix after A (or B) has undergone an even number of row and column swaps. They therefore have the same determinant.

Is there a unique way of representing A and B in some sort of "normal" form, given they have this similarity, where one can say that if two matrices have the same "normal" form, they are identical up to row and column swaps?

Comment: Since swapping rows is the same as multiplying by permutation matrices on the right, and swapping columns is the same as multiplying by permutation matrices on the left, you could say that the two matrices belong to the same double coset $S_n \backslash M_{n \times n} / S_n$.  (This does not keep track of the parity of the swaps.)

Comment: An even number of row swaps and an even number of column swaps, or an even number of swaps between rows and columns?

Comment: The total number of swaps is even. Whatever keeps the determinant the same.

Comment: @JBL replacing $S_n \times S_n$ by the kernel of $(\operatorname{sgn} \sigma)(\operatorname{sgn} \tau)$ that seems to be an answer, but somewhat tautological.